# Why are my `RoBERTa` model outputs the same every time?

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, nlp, huggingface-transformers

I made my model for assing score about corpus based on RoBERTa(fine-tuning).

```py
class TF_RoBERTa_VAD_Classification(tf.keras.Model):
    def __init__(self, model_name):
        super(TF_RoBERTa_VAD_Classification, self).__init__()

        self.model_name = model_name
        self.roberta = TFRobertaModel.from_pretrained(model_name, from_pt=True)

        self.output_layer = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, kernel_initializer=tf.keras.initializers.TruncatedNormal(0.02), activation="linear", name="Linear_Output") # Initializer function test
    
    def call(self, inputs):
        input_ids, attention_mask = inputs

        outputs = self.roberta(input_ids=input_ids, attention_mask=attention_mask)
        cls_token = outputs[1]

        outputs = self.output_layer(cls_token)

        return outputs

    def get_config(self):
        config = super().get_config()
        config.update({
            "model_name": self.model_name,
        })
        return config

    @classmethod
    def from_config(cls, config):
        model = cls(config["model_name"])
        return model
```

This is my model's code.

When I trained my model, the loss(MSE) was changing but val_loss(MSE) doesn't change from 1epoch to 10~15epochs.

I tried to add a "gelu" layer before linear output layer but it still shows the same value.

How to resolve this?

Comment: MSE is a regression loss, why are you using it for classification? Obviously it does not work.

Comment: It isnt for classification. Regression.

Comment: I want to score to corpus